# Explanation for |x|=-x if x<0

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Can someone explain $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$ . I've proven various theorems in my real analysis text for homework, but I cannot see how $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$ makes sense.

Comment: If $x$ is negative what's the sign of $-x$?

Comment: I had the same trouble with this at one time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a contradiction. Say $x<0$. This means that $x$ is negative, therefore $-x$ is positive. If $x$ is negative, then its absolute value is $-x$.

You can think of $x$ as $x=-r$, where $r>0$. Then $|x| = |-r|=r=-(-r)=-x$.

Comment: Looking back at this now, it's too simple.